# Adding empty parameters to signature with Retrofit

Tags: android, oauth, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an Android app that communicates with an API (Jersey with OAuth v1) that uses RQL. This is done by using the Retrofit 2 library. 
To limit the data I've fetched, the *limit(limit, offset)* parameter is added to the URL. This wasn't easy, because Retrofit doesn't allow me to add empty parameters to a URL. 
 For example, this is my base URL: `api.acme.com/v1` and this is the users endpoint: `api.acme.com/v1/users`. But when I want to limit the amount of returned users, I want to use `api.acme.com/users?limit(10,2)`.

Because there was no option to add a variable name parameter with no value, the only method that didn't return an error was to generate the url like so:

```
@GET Call<UserList> getUsers (@Url String path);
```

and to pass this URL: `http://api.acme.com/users?limit(10,2)`

The error that returns is `{"error":1,"error_name":"OAUTH_SIGNATURE_EXCEPTION","error_message":"The OAuth signature is invalid"}`

This is because empty parameters are not added to the URL when generating the OAuth signature. Postman has the option to add these empty parameters to thesignature, but I can't seem to find this option in Retrofit. Any ideas ? Other options to add empty parameters to my URL are also always welcome !
I've already tried with Map, Paths and Query, but no results.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty parameters are not added to the URL"?

Comment: Do you have control over the web service?

Comment: @Emma The empty parameter in this case is "limit(10,2)" (a key without a value) For the generation of the OAuth signature, empty parameters are not added. In Postman there is an option to add these, but I can't find this option in retrofit

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, (assuming /v1/ is consistently there regardless of limit params, assuming you missed in 1 place in your question.), you can do this. This is a none standard way, though. It's a workaround and looks a bit ugly.

Retrofit baseUrl: "http://api.acme.com/v1/"

```
@GET("{user}")
Call<UserList> getUsers(@Path("user") String user);
```

If you do `getUsers("users")`, this resolves to "http://api.acme.com/v1/users"

If you do `getUsers("users?limit(10,2)")`, this resolves to "http://api.acme/com/v1/users?limit(10,2)".  (You might add url encoding here.)

If you possibly can ask for a change in the API, I would recommend to change the limit to standard query parameters format.

ex) limit=X&offset=Y

In this format, you can simply use @Query.

Comment: Thanks! This works for the users endpoint. When I try to execute this query: "http://api.acme.com/v1/?limit(20,0)" with your method, I get the error "URL query string "{x}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query."

Comment: No path between "v1/" and "?"?  What is the a full path that you try to hit?